# Script to remove IPs or network ranges from an IP space

Tags: networking, ip

As per the tittle, I have a tool that accepts both lists of IPs or network ranges (CIDR format) to perform a task. Unfortunately, it does not support exclusions of IPs or ranges from the IP space created.

For example, say I wanted to add the whole IP space to the tool; I would say: add 0.0.0.0/0.

But now let's say I want to exclude 192.168.0.0/16 from it; I don't have the means to do that, so I would need to find a way to create a range from 0.0.0.0-192.167.255.255 and another from 192.169.0.0-255.255.255.255. And this would have to be using CIDR notation.

Fair enough, with a bit of work I could figure out the above.

But the problem is that I need to do this on a frequent basis and with several exclusions, so I need to find a way to automate this.

Say: remove (192.168.1.0/24 192.168.85.1 224.0.0.0/8) from 0.0.0.0/0

I would then just keep adding to the list in parenthesis as and when required.

This would then produce a list of CIDR ranges to cover the whole 0.0.0.0/0 IP space, minus the exclusions above.

I couldn't find any tool out there that would do this, so was thinking about a script. I'm not too bothered about the language: perl, python, PHP, ruby, bash, whatever, will all do. I just need to solve the problem.

Any pointers?

Thanks,

JD

Comment: I wrote an answer but overlooked that you can't exclude anything.. in that case you already answered your own question. Your script would have to be smart enough to deduce the ranges that exclude as intended.

Comment: Yeah, that's the thing. I was hoping to find someone with a similar experience or with the knowledge of some IP/CIDR handling libraries to facilitate this.